# Spring Declarative Transaction Rollback fails for even after stating to roll back

Tags: java, spring, transactions

The problem is even after stating to rollback for Exception.class still transaction is not
rollbacked.

1.My datasource

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salesforce" />
              <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
            <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
        </beans:bean>
```

2. Transaction Manager

   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                     20
                     true
                     update

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

   <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </beans:bean>
   ```
3. and the declarative transaction at service layer

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
           public void saveEmployee(Long roleId, Long divId, Long areaId, Employee emp) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               employeeDao.saveEmployee(roleId, divId, areaId, emp);
           }
4. and after saving the employee i try to update a field and once i got null pointer
   exception thought it was roll backed but it was not the method is :

   public void saveEmployee(Long roleId, Long divId, Long areaId,Employee emp) {
       Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       EmployeeRole empRole = null;
       Division div = null;
       Area area = null;
       Employee cord = null;
       String materialPath = null;

   ```
   try{
       empRole = (EmployeeRole) session.get(EmployeeRole.class, roleId);
       div = (Division) session.get(Division.class, divId);
       area = (Area) session.get(Area.class, areaId);
       emp.setArea(area); 
       emp.setDivision(div);
       emp.setEmployeeRole(empRole);
       long employId = (Long) session.save(emp);

       cord = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, emp.getEmployeeCoordinaterId());
       materialPath = cord.getMaterialPath()+"."+employId;       
       emp.setMaterialPath(materialPath);
       emp.setEmployeeId(employId);
       session.saveOrUpdate(emp);      
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing to throw exception , add throw e; in catch block E.g.

```
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate very silly of me sorry cant up vote low on points.how can it catch if i dont throw ha ha.

Comment: @user3829082 Glad it helps :) . Remember by accepting an answer you also gain point :)